# C preprocessor loop until n is zero

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to create something like this for a lot of buttons:

```
#define NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_X      (600u)
#define NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_Y      (0U)
#define NAV_MENU_STOP_PIXEL_X       (800U)
#define NAV_MENU_STOP_PIXEL_Y       (480U)

#define NAV_MENU_WIDTH              (NAV_MENU_STOP_PIXEL_X - NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_X)
#define NAV_MENU_HEIGHT             (NAV_MENU_STOP_PIXEL_Y - NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_Y)

#define BUTTON_WIDTH                (NAV_MENU_WIDTH - 20)
#define BUTTON_HEIGHT               (40U)

#define BUTTON_0_START_PIXEL_X      (NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_X + 10)
#define BUTTON_0_START_PIXEL_Y      (NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_Y + 100)
#define BUTTON_0_STOP_PIXEL_X       (BUTTON_0_START_PIXEL_X + NAV_MENU_WIDTH)
#define BUTTON_0_STOP_PIXEL_Y       (BUTTON_0_START_PIXEL_Y + BUTTON_HEIGHT)

#define BUTTON_1_START_PIXEL_X      (NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_X + 10)
#define BUTTON_1_START_PIXEL_Y      (BUTTON_0_STOP_PIXEL_Y + 10)
#define BUTTON_1_STOP_PIXEL_X       (BUTTON_1_START_PIXEL_X + NAV_MENU_WIDTH)
#define BUTTON_1_STOP_PIXEL_Y       (BUTTON_1_START_PIXEL_Y + BUTTON_HEIGHT)

#define BUTTON_2_START_PIXEL_X      (NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_X + 10)
#define BUTTON_2_START_PIXEL_Y      (BUTTON_1_STOP_PIXEL_Y + 10)
#define BUTTON_2_STOP_PIXEL_X       (BUTTON_2_START_PIXEL_X + NAV_MENU_WIDTH)
#define BUTTON_2_STOP_PIXEL_Y       (BUTTON_2_START_PIXEL_Y + BUTTON_HEIGHT)

#define BUTTON_3_START_PIXEL_X      (NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_X + 10)
#define BUTTON_3_START_PIXEL_Y      (BUTTON_2_STOP_PIXEL_Y + 10)
#define BUTTON_3_STOP_PIXEL_X       (BUTTON_3_START_PIXEL_X + NAV_MENU_WIDTH)
#define BUTTON_3_STOP_PIXEL_Y       (BUTTON_3_START_PIXEL_Y + BUTTON_HEIGHT)
```

The Button0 is the first button, and all next button position depend of the previous one. I have tried to check at pre-processor concatenation to make this clean but I am not able to find a good way.

My idea was to do something like this:

```
#define BUTTON_0_START_PIXEL_X      (NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_X + 10)
#define BUTTON_0_START_PIXEL_Y      (NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_Y + 100)
#define BUTTON_0_STOP_PIXEL_X       (BUTTON_0_START_PIXEL_X + NAV_MENU_WIDTH)
#define BUTTON_0_STOP_PIXEL_Y       (BUTTON_0_START_PIXEL_Y + BUTTON_HEIGHT)

#define BUTTON_START_PIXEL_X(n)     (NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_X + 10)
#define BUTTON_START_PIXEL_Y(n)     (BUTTON_STOP_PIXEL_Y(n-1) + 10)
#define BUTTON_STOP_PIXEL_X(n)      (BUTTON_START_PIXEL_X(n) + NAV_MENU_WIDTH)
#define BUTTON_STOP_PIXEL_Y(n)      (BUTTON_START_PIXEL_Y(n) + BUTTON_HEIGHT)
```

However, I am stuck to find a way to make it work with the button(0) that initialize the rest of buttons. The solution would be to detect when "n" or "n-1" is equal to 0, and if this case, but I don't manage to encapsulate #if inside #define macro.

Comment: Macros don't support recursion, but you don't need it here. Since all buttons have the same height, you can multiply it (plus the gap size) by `n`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it is true that I am trying to overcomplicate the thing and your solution work. However, I am still curious if there is a way to do it. Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: [C Pre-Processor Magic](http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic) describes some advanced macro techniques, including recursion.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at it, unroll the recusion and just:

```
#define BUTTON_START_PIXEL_X(n)     (NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_X + 10)
#define BUTTON_START_PIXEL_Y(n)     (NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_Y + n * 10)
#define BUTTON_STOP_PIXEL_X(n)      (NAV_MENU_START_PIXEL_X + n * 10 + NAV_MENU_WIDTH)
#define BUTTON_STOP_PIXEL_Y(n)      (BUTTON_START_PIXEL_Y(n) + BUTTON_HEIGHT)
```

Or something similar.